# Passing in login credentials when making REST calls using Restangular

Tags: python, angularjs, restangular

I am writing an application that creates data via REST. An example while using requests in python to save a patient would be

```
pt = requests.post('http://localhost:8080/openmrs/ws/rest/v1/patient',data=json.dumps(patientPayload),headers=headers,auth=HTTPBasicAuth('myusername','mypassword'))
```

How can one simulate this using Restangular 
These are examples that i found that are not working

```
return Restangular.all('user/session/authenticate').post({user_id: user_id, password: password});
```

OR

```
var login = Restangular.one('auth').customPOST(
{grant_type:'password', username:'b@t.com', password:'666666', scope:'app'},
'token',
{},
{
    Authorization:'Basic ' + client,
    ContentType:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
```

);

Comment: you can try something like `RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({'Authorization': 'Basic ' + encoded});` where encoded is base64 encode of "username:password"

Comment: If it's just basic auth what you need, you can do exactly what @ashu is telling you.